# How to add rewrite roles in Plesk

Tags: blazor-webassembly, plesk

I need to publish a Blazor WebAssembly app. As you know, Blazor WebAssembly has some rewrite roles. I need to define the following roles:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="httpdocs\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="httpdocs\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I try to add the roles to `web.config`, but it did not work.
How can I add the roles in Plesk?